# Prioritizing $PATH Executables Over User Function with Same Name?

Tags: bash, shell

- I have `./bin` in my `$PATH`.
- I have a function `serve()` defined in one of the files my `~/.bashrc` sources.
- I have a script at `/Users/deefour/some/project/bin/serve`

When I `cd` into `/Users/deefour/some/project` and run

```
➜ serve
```

The `serve()` function is being executed. Is there a way to give the `bin/serve` script priority, without explicitly running

```
➜ ./bin/serve
```

or generally, is there a way to give commands found via `$PATH` lookup **priority** over user defined functions with the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run

```
command serve
```

...then this will ignore any function named `serve`, and only execute an external command from PATH.

---

Alternately, you can write the function to fall through to an external command when one exists:

```
serve() {
  if type -P serve >/dev/null; then
    command serve "$@"
  else
    # ...function contents here...
  fi
}
```

As another alternative, you can create a namespace of "fallback" functions, and call them from the `command_not_found_handle` hook:

```
command_not_found_handle() {
  if type "fallback__$1" >/dev/null; then
    "fallback__$@"
  else
    printf 'Command not found: %q\n' "$1" >&2
    return 127
  fi
}
fallback__serve() {
  # your normal serve function
}
```

Comment: I like this, but my ideal is to type nothing additional from the command line. What I'm looking for is, if `./bin/serve` exists, run that, if not, run the `serve()` function sourced from `~/.bashrc`. Ideally, something that isn't specific to this one command.

Comment: If that's what you want, then you'll want to define the function differently. I can think of a few approaches -- either you define your catch-all command-not-found handler to search a function namespace, or you write your function to first look for a command in PATH with the same name and only proceed if that isn't found.

Comment: Ah, I think I can make something work based on your edit and the "catch-all command-not-found handle" idea. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! I was actually working on the catchall-hook implementation as you typed that -- I hope it comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write

```
`which serve`
```

instead of

```
serve
```

Or even something like that

```
run_executable() {
    program="$1"
    fullname=`which "$program"`
    [ "$?" -eq 0 ] || return 127
    "$fullname"
}
run_executable serve
```

Comment: Why check `$?` explicitly? `local fullname; fullname=$(which "$1") || return 127`

Comment: (if you don't explicitly declare your locals, they're created in global scope -- bash functions' variables leak into global scope by default just like javascript's do).

Answer (score -1):

I seem to remember using \command to override aliases.  This may also work for overriding functions.  I'm not at a computer right now to test it.

Comment: Do the downvoters *think* this won't work, or do they *know* it won't work?

Comment: Downvoting with no accompanying comment as to why is cowardly, imho.  Please help me understand how to improve the answer, or at least correct it.